# SQL - Combine a select * query with select 1

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to combine data from two tables in one result. With simplified example-tables, this is what I want to get in result:

```
ID    Text                Choice
--------------------------------
1     My first choice     0
2     My second choice    0
3     My third choice     1
```

from the two tables persons and choosen

'Persons':

```
ID      Name    Age
-------------------
1       Adam    22
2       Scott   25
3       Tom     28
```

'Choices':

```
ID    Text
----------------------
1     My first choice
2     My second choice
3     My third choice
```

'Choices_made':

```
Person_ID    Choice_ID
----------------------
2            3
```

I have tried some different queries, but not found the right one. I got stuck when trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM Choices) t1
UNION
(SELECT 1 as Choice FROM Choices_made WHERE Person_ID=2) t2
) t_union
```

... which does not work. It causes error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish the wanted result?

Comment: can you explain columns of your expected result? Also, column count of select queries used for union is different, which is resulting in error. i.e. SELECT * FROM Choices returns returns result set with 2 column, while SELECT 1 as Choice FROM Choices_made WHERE Person_ID=2 returns single column.

Comment: What do the two tables have in common?

Comment: The result should be a complete list over the rows in table 'Choices' but with an extra column 'Choice' that indicates what choice(s) the person (Scott) has chosen.

Comment: The two tables ('Persons' and 'Choices') does not have anything in common, they are just combined in the third table ('Choices_made') by their primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the next query

```
SELECT Choices.*
      ,IF(Choices_made.Choice_ID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Choice
FROM Choices
     LEFT JOIN Choices_made ON Choices_made.Choice_ID = Choices.ID AND Choices_made.Person_ID = @PersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.text, 
       cm.Choice_ID = c.id as persons_choice
FROM Choices c
LEFT JOIN Choices_made cm on cm.Choice_ID = c.id
                         and cm.Person_ID = 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get what I wanted.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the null-values with zeros?

Answer (score 0):

You could use left join
then use case when when setting the 3rd field to 1 or zero

```
SELECT p.id as , c.text, 
CASE 
WHEN cm.choice_id <> 0 then 1
ELSE 
0
END
as Choice
from persons as p
left join choices as c on c.id = p.id
left join choices_made as cm on cm.personid = p.id
```